# Rails 4 and globalize: fields for different languages at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

I have a multilingual website. For translations I use `globalize` gem.

I want to give an user two text fields on the same page.
User can fill one of them, or both. 
I want to save records for all locales on submit button clicked.

Say, there are two text fields named `username`.
I can type `Ivan` for English one, and `Иван` for Russian one.
When I click `Submit` button, I want to see two records in my `user_translations` table for `en` and `ru` respectively.

What's the most elegant way to get that worked?

ps: [batch_translations](https://github.com/fidel/batch_translations) seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved with [globalize-accessors](https://github.com/globalize/globalize-accessors)

Comment: I'm using globalize-accessors, trying to update multiple translated fields for multiple nested attributes in one only form. 
But, only when I update the default language with a new changed text, it will update also the other languages. 
If I update other language than the default it do not save the content. 
What could be wrong in my config?